# Set post thumbnail as background

Tags: post-thumbnails

I have a single page for my products where all products get listed. This is how i've archieved it:

```
<ul class="produkte">
    <?php $args = array( 'post_type' => 'produkte', 'posts_per_page' => 30 );

    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
        echo '<li class="produkt">';
        echo '<a href="' . get_permalink() . '">';
        echo '<div class="produkt-info">';
        the_title('<h3>', '</h3>');
        if (has_post_thumbnail()) {
            echo '<figure class="imgBox">';
           the_post_thumbnail('full', array('class' => 'img-resp') );
           echo "</figure>";
        }
        echo '</div>';
        echo '</a>';
        echo '</li>';
    endwhile; ?>
</ul>
```

I decided that i want to set the post thumbnail as the background-image of the li.produkt. When i do something like this:

```
echo '<li class="produkt" style="background: url('.the_post_thumbnail().')">';
```

The page generates an image-element above the li-element. What am i doing wrong??

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem here is `the_post_thumbnail()` doesn't return image url but the img tag.

You can use this code

```
$url = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) );
echo '<li class="produkt" style="background: url('. $url.')">';
```

Answer (score 9):

There is now the `get_the_post_thumbnail_url` function provided in WordPress.

Usage example from the codex:

`$featured_img_url = get_the_post_thumbnail_url(get_the_ID(),'full');`

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_post_thumbnail_url/

Answer (score 3):

Per WordPress Codex the the_post_thumbnail() function ***Display the post thumbnail.*** https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_post_thumbnail/ But this output the whole image tag and not just the src, which in your case is needed.

Instead you should use the wp_get_attachment_image_src() function which ***Retrieve an image to represent an attachment.***. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image_src/

So i suggest to try something like this:

```
//this retrieve the full version of image
$image_data = wp_get_attachment_image_src ( get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID), 'full' );
$image_url = $image_data[0];
echo '<li class="produkt" style="background: url('. $image_url .')">';
```

Comment: Just pay attention that you have a bracket ")" more at the end of your first row.

Answer (score 1):

Try using background-size: cover, background-position: center and background-size: 300px 100px;

```
<?php
echo '<li class="produkt" style="background-image: url('<?php the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>'); background-size: cover; background-position: center; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: 300px 100px;">';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

simply echo the post thumbnail url :

`<li class="produkt" style="background-image: url(<?php echo the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>);">></li>`